# Fancy box transition effect broken

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

The transition effect in the code below is broken, instead of fading in, the fancybox just jumps up from the top of the window down in the middle.
How can I make this work correctly?

```
  window.onload = function() {
        $(function(){
                function showfb(id) {
                    if (/^#.*/.test(id)) {
                        $(id).show();
                        $.fancybox({
                            href: id,
                            type:'inline',
                            'transitionIn': 'fade', // elastic, none, ease, fade
                            'transitionOut': 'fade',
                            onClosed: function() {
                                $(id).hide();
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
                showfb(location.hash);
                $('a.profile').click(function(e){
                        showfb($(this).attr('href'));
                });
        });
  };
```

Comment: is there any reason to hide/show the inline content before showing in fancybox? fancybox would normally hide the inline content so I don't see the reason to hide it on close. BTW, what version of fancybox?

Comment: @JFK I am using v1.3.4. And btw as you mentioned. The code above works when I open the article on fancybox and it changes the url to /whatever#profile-1 but then when I close fancybox the url stays the same. I would like to remove that #profile-1 again.
The problem mentioned above is still occurring, I've been trying to find out why, but no success. Fancybox keeps having that weird transission when it opens up, but when I go at the bottom of the page and open another profile, it works just fine, which made me think of content line-up. But it's not that either.